# Lyx - external program error - NO LOGS

Tags: pdftex, errors, lyx, ps2pdf

I am getting the following error whenever exporting to pdf:

> The external program
> latex
> finished with an error. It is recommended you fix the cause of the external program's error (check the logs).

Document > Latex Logs is grayed out, so I am unable to check the logs.

I get this error with multiple export methods (pdflatex, ps2pdf) and with every single Lyx file, including ones that had successfully exported to pdf in the past, so I think the issue is with Lyx or the latex backend, not the files I'm trying to export.

Am using LyX Version 2.3.6.1

What should I look at for diagnostics?

Comment: Did you try to start (PDF)LaTeX directly (for example from the command line by just typing `latex` or `pdflatex`)? Is it even installed on your machine?

Comment: If you are sure that you have LateX correctly installed, only once, and working, then → Tools → Reconfigure → Restart LyX. Otherwise  → Tools → TeX Information → Click in "Show paths" and check if LyX sees everything only once, and where it should be.

Comment: Thank you, all. It turned out to be an install error from a failed update.